# Is there a way to configure parenthesizerRules?

Tags: typescript-compiler-api

I am using the typescript compiler API to build typescript from scratch.

I have encountered an issue where `ts.factory.createBinaryExpression` results in parenthesis being added when multiple logical and statements are chained together.

This seems to be based on the parenthesizerRules, specifically this line (in `typescript.ts`) and some sub calls:

```js
node.right = parenthesizerRules().parenthesizeRightSideOfBinary(operatorKind, node.left, right);
```

Example code as follows:

```js
import ts from 'typescript'

const printNodes = (node: ts.Node): string => {
    const printer = ts.createPrinter({ newLine: ts.NewLineKind.LineFeed, omitTrailingSemicolon: true });
    return printer.printNode(ts.EmitHint.Unspecified, node, ts.createSourceFile("file.ts", "", ts.ScriptTarget.Latest, /*setParentNodes*/ false, ts.ScriptKind.TS))
}

const x = ts.factory.createIdentifier("x")
const y = ts.factory.createIdentifier("y")
const binary = ts.factory.createBinaryExpression(
    x,
    ts.SyntaxKind.LessThanToken,
    y
)

// binary expression: x < y
console.log(`binary expression: ${printNodes(binary)}`)

const logical_and = ts.factory.createBinaryExpression(binary, ts.SyntaxKind.AmpersandAmpersandToken,
    ts.factory.createBinaryExpression(
    x, ts.SyntaxKind.LessThanToken, ts.factory.createNumericLiteral(10))
)

// logical_and: x < y && x < 10
console.log(`logical_and: ${printNodes(logical_and)}`)

const logical_and_and = ts.factory.createBinaryExpression(binary, ts.SyntaxKind.AmpersandAmpersandToken, logical_and)
// logical_and_and: x < y && (x < y && x < 10)
console.log(`logical_and_and: ${printNodes(logical_and_and)}`)
```

The output I require is

```
x < y && x < y && x < 10
```

The code in `typescript.js` seems to be performing operator precedence comparisons to determine whether parenthesis are required.

I am importing code from another language, so I need to copy the exact logic.
The situation above seems OK for `&&`, but once a few `||`s are mixed in, things stop working as intended.

typescript version: `5.3.3`